# How to use facebook api version 1.0 instead of 2.0

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I want to use facebook api 1.0. Is it possible to mention its version directly in the code, like in `facebook->api()` call? or give me a download link for it. I searched for its download link but i couldnt find it.

I want to use v1.0 because there is something which v2.0 is not supporting, like read_requests permissions to get user's friend requests or if there is way to get friend requests in v2.0 please mention it in your answer.

Comment: When did you create your app? that will determine if can you use v1.0 or not

Comment: i created my app some 12 days ago.

Comment: Sorry to break your heart, you're locked with API 2.0

Comment: OH :(
is there any way to get friend requests with v2.0?

Comment: You can check [`/me/invitable_friends`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/invitable_friends/)

Comment: well, This method is only accessible to Games. :(

Comment: @AdamAzad Definitely read that as "`/me/inevitable_friends`" at first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> i created my app some 12 days ago.

As the [Platform Versioning](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/versions) page refers to, you are probably out of luck:

> **Can my app make calls to versions older than the current version?**
>
> If your app was created before the launch of v2.0 `[April 30, 2014]`, while v1.0 was available, then it will be able to make calls to v1.0 until the expiration date of that version `[April 30, 2015]`.

**EDIT:** As [WizKid mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24686487/how-to-use-facebook-api-version-1-0-instead-of-2-0/24686648#comment38281387_24686648), apps that existed before 4/30/2014 can use v1.0 of the API. According to [the f8 dev blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2014/04/30/the-new-facebook-login) on 4/30/2014:

> ...existing apps have a full year to upgrade (April 30, 2015).

Comment: if the application is more than six months old, then?

Comment: If the app was active before 4/30/2014 you can use v1.0