# Facebook android : Adding a friend

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Learning android and the Facebook SDK, i wanted to allow the connected user to Add a friend When he click on the add button, I can get the user-that-will-be-added Id.

I can't use the Friend Dialog because it's no more supported after version 2.0 in the facebook SDK.
I searched and didn't found any working solution, if someone knows the answer please help.

Comment: As you mention, this is not possible as it is no longer supported in version 2.0 (possibly because this sort of behavior can be considered "spammy"). You can simply add a link to the profile in question, allowing the user to natively send a friend request.

Comment: If i use the previous version of the sdk, will i be able to send add friend requests ?

Comment: If you had access to version 1.0, then yes, but as I answered awhile back, [it's not possible to use version 1.0 unless your app existed before April 30th of this year](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24686648/1454048).

Comment: What about the news feed or user timeline, do you have some good links ?

Comment: @admdrew What about the news feed or user timeline ?